# Inheriting Attributes from Classes in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, parent-child, subclass, super

I need the *_plot* function to be able to access *dataClass*'s *.name* attribute so that the graph would have the title *Aluminum*. However, I keep getting the error:

*AttributeError: type object 'dataClass' has no attribute 'name'*

How can I get _plot to inherit *dataClass*'s *.name* attribute?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt.

class dataClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name, dictionary):
        self.name = name
        self.add_model(dictionary)
    def add_model(self, dictionary):
        model_name = dictionary['model']
        setattr(self, model_name, _model(model_name)
        *there is some code here which gives real vales to model.data, model.error, and model.xaxis*

class _model(dataClass):
    def __init__(self, model_name):
        self.modelname = model_name
        self.data = None
        self.error = None
        self.xaxis = None

    def _plot(self, fig=None, ax=111, xaxis=None, **kwargs):
        if fig is None:                     # no figure given
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = plt.subplot(ax)
        elif isinstance(ax, (int, float)):  # figure given
            ax = fig.add_subplot(ax)
        else:                               # figure and axis given
            pass
        if xaxis is None:
            xaxis = self.xaxis
        super(_model,self).__init__   # this line doesn't work
        name = dataClass.name         # this line raises the error
        name = ax.errorbar(xaxis, self.data, yerr=self.error, ls='-', label=name)
        handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
        ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper right')
        return fig

def makePlot(xAxis, thing_to_plot):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    thing_to_plot._plot(fig, ax, xAxis)
    plt.title("Measured and Best Fit Function")
    plt.savefig("lineplots2.png")
    plt.close(fig)

Dust = dataClass('Dust', {'model': 'raw', 'data': [eqn.dustRatio(const)*eqn.dust(l) for l in lDict['lList']]})
makePlot(lDict['lList'], Dust.raw)
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I had found a post elsewhere on Stack Overflow which gave some suggestions for how to make objects add themselves to existing plots. I took the code and edited it to this. Now I am trying to make this practice function part of my actual code

```
class Plotter(object):
    def __init__(self, xval=None, yval=None):
        self.xval = xval
        self.yval = yval
        self.error = None

    def plotthing(self, fig=None, index=1):
        if fig is None:
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = plt.subplot(111)
        else:
            ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,index)
        name = 'curve{}'.format(1)
        name = ax.errorbar(self.xval, self.yval, yerr=self.error, ls='-', label=name)
        handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
        ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper right')
        return fig


def compareplots(*args):
    fig = plt.figure()
    for i, val in enumerate(args):
        val.plotthing(fig, i+1)
        plt.title("Measured and Best Fit Function")
    return fig

app1 = Plotter(xval=range(0,10), yval=range(0,10))
plot1 = app1.plotthing()
plot1.savefig('testlong.png')
app2 = Plotter(xval=range(0,11), yval=range(1,12))

thingummy = compareplots(app1, app2)
thingummy.savefig('test.png')
```

Comment: This is a very strange code. Without knowing what it is supposed to do, it's difficult to help.

Comment: It stores telescope data that was processed in different ways as _models_ of the object. When I want to make large plots with different pieces of data, the object._plot function can (if passed a figure) add itself to the plot

Comment: You have two related classes with business logic spread between them. Please show how you create the class instance and how you call the method which causes the exception. Also `{'model': 'Thermal Conductivity'}` along with `setattr(self, model_name, _model(model_name))` means you will have attribute with name `'Thermal Conductivity'` which you will not be able to access normally. What is that `test._plot` on the last line?

Comment: I updated the code to be more representative of what I have written

Comment: `super(_model,self).__init__(...)` this line should be in `_model.__init__`, but I am not sure it is correct to inherit `_model` from `dataClass`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the exception happens on this line:

```
name = dataClass.name
```

Here you are trying to access class attribute of class `dataClass` which doesn't exist:

```
class dataClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name, dictionary):
        self.name = name
        self.add_model(dictionary)
```

Here you've created instance attribute, which you can access if you have the instance.

> How can I get _plot to inherit dataClass's .name attribute?

`_model` class instances automatically inherit this attribute.
I guess you meant to use `name = self.name` instead of `name = dataClass.name`, though this leaves me in doubt:

```
def _plot(self, fig=None, ax=111, xaxis=None, **kwargs):
    if fig is None:
        fig = plt.figure()
    super(_model,self).__init__()
```

You are calling parent class "constructor" from a non-constructor method.

Comment: yeah, 'name = self.name' does not work. The new error message is _AttributeError: '_model' object has no attribute 'name'_

Answer (score 0):

There are two things (that I know of) that you could be trying to do. You could be attempting to access a class attribute, or you are trying to access an instance attribute. If you want the first, you would need your dataClass to be something like this:

```
class dataClass(object):
    name = 'jim'
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.add_model(dictionary)
    def add_model(self, dictionary):
        model_name = dictionary['model']
        setattr(self, model_name, _model(model_name))
```

If you are trying to access a class attribute assigned by the setattr() in the add_model method, then you will have to access it by using dataClass."model_name" where model name is the name of the model you want to access.

If you are trying to access an instance attribute, you will have to pass an instance of the dataClass object to the _model to the method, or do something similar to that. The overall structure of your program is very confusing, as I am not really sure what objective you are trying to accomplish by accessing the attribute this way, as well as the way in which you are adding attributes to the dataClass object.

If you just want to inherit the class attribute, then you need only use the code above. I am not sure what, exactly, you mean by inherit, since it doesn't seem like inheritance is really what you are after. If you could clarify your intentions, that would be very heplful.

**EDIT:**
After getting a better idea of what you are trying to do, I think a better way of accessing that information would be with classes like this:

```
class dataClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name, dictionary):
        self.name = name
        self.models = {}
        self.add_model(dictionary)

    def add_model(self, dictionary):
        model_name = dictionary['model']
        if 'data' in dictionary:
            data = dictionary['data']
        else:
            data = None
        self.models.update({model_name : data})

class model(object):
    def __init__(self, model_name):
        self.modelname = model_name

    def plot(self, thing_to_plot , fig=None, ax=111, xaxis=None, **kwargs):
        # do meaningful work here
        return thing_to_plot.name

example = dataClass('Aluminum', {'model': 'Thermal Conductivity'})
thing = model("doug")

print("Plotted object's name: %s" % thing.plot(example))
print("_model name: %s" % thing.modelname)
```

Hopefully that will be more useful.

Comment: It stores telescope data that was processed in different ways as models of the object. When I want to make large plots with different pieces of data, the object._plot function can (if passed a figure) add itself to an existing plot

Comment: Are you trying to have a single instance of the dataClass object, and have all _model objects access it?

Comment: It stores telescope data that was processed in different ways as models of the object. When I want to make large plots with different pieces of data, the object._plot function can (if passed a figure) add itself to an existing plot. For the plot title, I need the name of the object; however the name is not stored as _object.model.name_ but _object.name_ the I can't get the plot function to access _object.name_

Comment: I understand what your intention is as far as functionality. I am asking _how_ you want to achieve it. Do you want a single instance of the dataClass object? What that means is, are you going to store all of the models within that dataClass? I do not think that inheritance is  what you want to use for this job.

Comment: I make something like 'Dust = dataClass('Dust', {'model': 'raw', 'data': [eqn.dustRatio(const)*eqn.dust(l) for l in lDict['lList']]});  Dust.add_model({'model': 'bin', 'data': fn.binData(Dust.raw.data, lDict['lList'])})' and also a whole bunch of other things like _Dust_ and then I want to plot all of the raw data models for every object so I make a figure and then use a for loop to pass the figure through each object's '_plot'  and they add themselves to the figure and I end up with a finished plot.

Comment: I edited my original answer with some code that I think will do what you are looking to do. Let me know if it is useful.